# Bank allowed to keep title

Tags: loans, co-sign

I co signed on loan and put my truck title as collateral, the one I co-signed for had went back borrowed more money without me knowing, so my name is now not on loan so can the bank still keep my title?

Comment: Sounds like almost more of a legal issue - the 'without you knowing' part might mean you have legal recourse available against the other party, if they forge your name/signature on the refinance.

Comment: We really need a tag for "tales-of-woe", or "mistakes-with-zeros-on-the-end".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the original loan is outstanding.